# Accordion: Open all Tabs

Tags: jquery

I want to activate all `Accordion Tabs` when the page loads.

```js
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        jQuery(".accordion").accordion({heightStyle: "content", collapsible: true, active: 0});
    });
```

```html
<div class="accordion" id="accordion">          
  <h3>This is Title 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>This is Content 1</p>
  </div>    

  <h3>his is Title 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>This is Content 2</p>
  </div>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you are missing out is just including the jquery files.

add the below line in the **`<head>`** tag

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

then after it wil be depend on us that how we want to manage the accordion.

Comment: Hello Punit, without jquery and jquery-ui accordion will not work. I wanted to active all accordion tabs open.

Comment: Hey @LitonArefin If you want to expand all then you should not use accordions.. better to use Expand/Collapse All. it would be better.. check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sinetheta/s5hAw/) example.

Comment: Got the solution using "collapsible". Used on ["WP Awesome FAQ Pro"](https://jeweltheme.com/product/wordpress-faq-plugin/)  Plugin . Thanks